# Python join directory paths

Tags: python, path, pathlib, os.path

I have problems with os.path.join() because it never joins complete path.
Code is:

```
get_base_dir = (os.getenv('BUILD_DIRECTORY'))
base_dir_path = pathlib.Path(get_base_dir)
print (base_dir_path ) # output is: F:\file\temp\ - which is correct

s_dir = '/sw/folder1/folder2/'
s_dir_path = pathlib.Path(s_dir)
print (s_dir_path) # output is: \sw\folder1\folder2\


full_path = os.path.join(base_dir_path, s_dir_path)

print (full_path)   # output is: F:\\sw\\folder1'\\folder2 instead of F:\\file\\temp\\sw\\folder1'\\folder2
```

Anyone has idea of what goes wrong?

Comment: could you add the output of `print(s_dir_path)` ?

Comment: sure updating now, output is as it should be

Comment: Please explain how your question is related to `azure` as you did used such tag

Comment: my bad, I forgot to remove that tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is compliant with what [`os.path.join` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) states

> Join one or more path components intelligently. The return value is
> the concatenation of path and any members of *paths with exactly one
> directory separator following each non-empty part except the last,
> meaning that the result will only end in a separator if the last part
> is empty. **If a component is an absolute path, all previous components
> are thrown away and joining continues from the absolute path
> component.**

(I added emphasis)

Comment: I am not sure if I understand this, it is not possible to do it this way?

Comment: This is because you have an absolute path on s_dir. You must remove the first slash.